# Why non-elastic deformations of solids are time dependent?

Tags: solid-state-physics, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

I'm learning the properties of viscoelasticity, and it is a common fact that non-elastic deformations are time dependent.
However, I don't understand what physically happens to the molecules that take time to react to the stress. In elastic deformation, the molecules stretch or shrink instantly around their location, and in nonelastic, there are impurities that actually move inside the lattice. Why is the movement time dependent? Is it just because of the velocity of the movement?
If someone can expand qualitatively the physics of the time dependent deformation it would be great.

Comment: How do you envision effects requiring mass transport to occur instantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plastic deformation, strain energy is stored in the deformed lattice network. To evolve into a lower-energy state, the locked-in strain fields (if tensile) tend to attract diffusing atoms towards them; compressive strain fields do the opposite. Diffusive transport in solids is thermally-activated which makes the strain relief process slow (as opposed to instantaneous) at room temperature for most materials.

BTW if you heat the deformed object up, more atoms will be "on the move" and the strain energy release rate goes up.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain why the thermally activated process makes the strain relief slow? Is it because it takes time to heat the area?

Comment: No, it is because at low temperatures very few of the atoms have the activation energy necessary to diffuse. This means not very many atoms will be taking part in the process, which makes it go slow.